# Is this a github profile readme bug?

Tags: github, profile

#### You can find I put a profile.png in my EggTronic/EggTronic's readme.

[image]

#### But!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!

#### Who the hell is this guy one my GitHub profile?

[image]

Comment: I’m voting to close this question because it doesn't belong on SO.

Comment: :D fair, but there is something over there - Github

Comment: Ok, I figured it out, this man is actually a Github user who's name is Profile...

Comment: I’m voting to close this question because this is not a programming question.

Answer (score 0):

It may be you are putting the wrong picture. You can google it but this question does not belong to this platform. I am voting to close this question.

Comment: There is no way to be the wrong picture, it's a bug or a hash collision.